# Get the language state of the currently active window in Python

Tags: python, keyboard

There are two languages ​​on my keyboard, Korean and English. When keyboard input comes, I need to know if it comes in Korean or English. Every solution I've found only in the run window, but not in other windows. Any ideas on how to get the language state in another window?